# Provide implementation for abstract method but restrict visibility

Tags: java, abstract-class, visibility

I have a method in an abstract class that calls an abstract method, for which the subclasses must provide the implementation.

```
public abstract class AClass {

    public void foo() {
        ...
        fooToImplement();
        ...
    }

    // DON'T CALL THIS METHOD, ONLY PROVIDE IMPLEMENTATION!
    protected abstract void fooToImplement();

}
```

I want to make sure that the subclasses don't call fooToImplement(), they should always use foo() instead. The behavior is something like a "private abstract" method, but that's not possible in Java.

Is there some alternative? Thanks!

Comment: The class calling "foo()" , shouldn't be a subclass of AClass , so that it has no way of seeing "fooToImplement" .

Comment: Why not? Even if it's public, foo() may be intended to be used internally by the subclass too. You can assume foo() is also protected if that helps.

Comment: replace inheritance with delegation.. you need to use delegation pattern..

Comment: I don't see a problem here. The class that implements this method can also call it. Always. None of the answers so far allow to (realistically) really *prevent* this. The API should not be a "firewall" in this regard. Although this should definitely not be the default assumption: At a certain point, one **has** to assume that the developer (implementor of the abstract method) knows what he's doing. The `protected abstract` combination and a JavaDoc comment explaining the intended usage should be sufficient here.

Comment: Google created an annotation with enforcement specifically for this: [`@ForOverride`](https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/master/annotations/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/annotations/ForOverride.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want your subclasses to be able to call this method you could use strategy: Extract the behavior of the method into an interface and pass an implementation of this interface to the object. E.g.

```
IStrategy {
  public void fooToImplement();
} 

AClass {
   public AClass(IStrategy impl) {...}

    public void foo() {
      ...
      strategy.fooToImplement();
      ...
    }
}
```

Delegation instead of inheritance. In java 8 this would be a little bit easier.

If your implementation of `IStrategy` would need access to the data of the object AClass, you could try to implement it as an inner class.

Comment: The only problem is that whoever implements IStrategy may have to be aware of the internal state of AClass' subclasses, although I guess you can use an internal class or an anonymous implementation nested in the subclass too. I will consider this option.

Answer (score 2):

The method has to be visible by your subclass if you want it to be overriden.
You have to use a class witch does not extends `AClass` as caller.

```
public class BClass extends ACLass {
   @Override 
   protected void fooToImplement() {
      System.out.println("override me im famous");
   }
}
```

```
public class CClass {
   private BCLass bInstance;
   public void doSomething(){
      bInstance.foo();
      // !!! NO ACCESS TO fooImplement()
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about using something like a decorator pattern, although I miss the simplicity of a visibility modifier like a theoretical "private abstract" modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Since `fooToImplement()` needs to be visible to subclasses to be implemented there and there's no way to distinguish between "implement visibility" and "execution rights", you can't do this by inheritance.

You could however combine your object with another object that contains `fooToImplement()` by composition:

```
interface FooImplementation {
    void fooToImplement(AClass a);
}

public abstract class AClass {

    private final FooImplementation fooImpl;
    protected AClass(FooImplementation fooImpl) {
         this.fooImpl = fooImpl;
    }

    public void foo() {
        ...
        fooImpl.fooToImplement(this);
        ...
    }

}
```

That wouldn't prevent anyone from outside the class from using `yourFooImpl.fooToImplement(yourAClass)` however. To prevent this you could create a class that provides the information that `fooToImplement()` needs, but that can only be instanciated from within `AClass`:

```
interface FooImplementation {
    void fooToImplement(AClass.AClassFooView a);
}

public abstract class AClass {

    private final FooImplementation fooImpl;

    protected AClass(FooImplementation fooImpl) {
        this.fooImpl = fooImpl;
    }

    public class AClassFooView {
        ...
        private AClassFooView() {
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        ...
        fooImpl.fooToImplement(this.new AClassFooView());
        ...
    }

}
```

But `fooToImplement` could pass the reference to `AClassFooView` to other classes...

However depending on the implementors of your class making absolutely sure in the documentation, that nobody should call `fooToImplement()` could also be an alternative.

Ultimately you have to trust the implementors, since there's also the the possibility of someone using reflection to get access to private members, reverse engeneering+changing+recompiling your class ect..

Comment: Yes, there are always workarounds, so probably just well documenting the class is the most reasonable option in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to this, for example add aspect @Before to fooToImplement() and check stacktrace of calling and throw IllegalArgumentException if fooToImplement() be called any method except foo(), something like:

```
if(!Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().equals("foo")) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("You musn't call fooToImplement() directly"+ 
", using foo() instead");
}
```

However this way has two problem:

1. perfomance
2. runtime exception